# Trying to install a theme with WordPress (FTP Failing)

Tags: wordpress, ftp, webserver

So a few weeks ago I setup my Raspberry Pi as a web server. I used this website to set it up:
http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server

After that, I added WordPress onto the little server using this tutorial:
http://mitchtech.net/wordpress-on-raspberry-pi/

As you can see, I'm very much a nub when it comes to these things, but my hope is using this website I will get a little better and development.

My current issue is that when i tried to install this new theme with WordPress, I am required to give the Hostname, FTP Usernam, and FTP Password (and select either FTP or FTPS) but I cant get pass this step.

Other than passwords, the usernames are still default from the tutorials.

Comment: what is your question? Be clear.

Comment: How are you installing the theme? You should log into wp-admin and do it from there; it won't require any credentials, other than your Wordpress admin credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your wp-config.php

`define('FS_METHOD','direct');`

Comment: While this could be the solution, could you elaborate a little more on this, and help the OP understand _why_ this tweak is needed, how it addresses/fixes the issue?

Comment: **FS_METHOD** forces the filesystem method. It should only be direct, ssh2, ftpext, or ftpsockets. Generally, you should only change this if you are experiencing update problems. If you change it and it doesn't help, change it back/remove it. Under most circumstances, setting it to 'ftpsockets' will work if the automatically chosen method does not.

Comment: ** (Secondary Preference) "ssh2" ** is to force the usage of the SSH PHP Extension if installed

** (3rd Preference) "ftpext" ** is to force the usage of the FTP PHP Extension for FTP Access, and finally

** (4th Preference) "ftpsockets" ** utilises the PHP Sockets Class for FTP Access

For more information visit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants